# Wordpress : How to add social media share button on my website?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I want to add facebook share button on my website, that should just post my website's content on the wall. who want to share it, i need to share link + title.

I have researched a lot but did not get anything. Pleas help me in this.

I have this code that suppose to work, but doesn't work. If this helps you in anyway that would be great.

i need for facebook, twitter, likein, google plus

```
 <a href="javascript:fb_shar();" class="string fb"></a>

                        <a href="javascript:(function(){window.twttr=window.twttr||{};var D=550,A=450,C=screen.height,B=screen.width,H=Math.round((B/2)-(D/2)),G=0,F=document,E;if(C&gt;A){G=Math.round((C/2)-(A/2))}window.twttr.shareWin=window.open('http://twitter.com/share','','left='+H+',top='+G+',width='+D+',height='+A+',personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');E=F.createElement('script');E.src='http://platform.twitter.com/bookmarklets/share.js?v=1';F.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(E)}());" class="string tw"></a>

                        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?summary=&title=<?=$rowB['title'];?>&mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&ro=false&source=" class="string in"></a>

                        <a href="javascript:pl_shar();" class="string pl"></a>
```

JS

```
function fb_shar()
{

var sharer = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=";
window.open(sharer + encodeURIComponent(document.URL), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436');
}
function pl_shar()
{
var sharer = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=";
window.open(sharer + document.URL, 'sharer', 'width=626,height=436');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use a plugin like [Sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/) that's going to have all the options you gonna need and have many other options.

Comment: i will try this but its share link only i need link with title

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Wordpress plugin. Like i.e. http://wordpress.org/plugins/sociable/